Solving the Differential Equation $ xy(x)y'(x) = y(x) - 1 $
I am given the differential equation:
$$ xyy' = y - 1 $$
I have tried to solve it by separating the variables, but I have only come this far:
$$ \int 1 + \frac{1}{y-1} dy = \int \frac{1}{x} dx = y + \log|y-1| = \log{|x|} + C $$
I am struggeling on how to isolate $ y(x) $. Can somebody please give me a hint on how to continue?

Your methodology so far is spot-on (there is a mistake in what you wrote where an $x$ should be a $1/x$, but since you write $\log |x|$ for the antiderivative, I'm assuming it's just a typo). I don't know how to make it better.

wolfram is giving a closed-form solution in terms of the lambert W-function, which makes me think there isn't a better way. Are you sure you have the right problem?

Maybe it was meant to be in the implicit form

@hunter Yes, thank you for bringing that to my attention. I have corrected the mistake.

If $y>1$, then $y+\ln\lvert y-1\rvert=\ln((y-1)e^y)$. Now apply the exponential to both sides, multiply by $e^{-1}$, and use the Lambert $W$ function

@hunter Yeah, I just double-checked. The problem is set like that.

@DheerajGujrathi Or just solved for $x$.

@user14111 Oh, yes, it should refer to the derivatives with respect to x. However, it might be a bit misleading. I have changed it.

You're on the right track. To solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ we need to invoke the Lambert $W$-function or its equivalent.
Write $u := y - 1$ and absorb the resulting constant on the right-hand side, so that the equation becomes
$$u + \log |u| = \log |x| + C$$
Exponentiating then gives
$$|u| e^u = C |x| .$$
Now, the Lambert $W$-function was designed to satisfy the equation $W(z) e^{W(z)} = z$, and for real-valued functions, it's enough to consider $2$ branches: The principal branch, $W_0 : \left[-\frac1e, \infty\right) \to [-1, \infty)$, and $W_{-1}: \left[-\frac1e, 0\right) \to (-\infty,-1]$.
If $u > 0$ ($y > 1$), the left-hand side of the previous display equation becomes $u e^u$, so we have the solution
$$u = W_a(C |x|)$$ or
$$y(x) = 1 + W_a(C |x|) .$$
So:

If $C > 0$, there is a solution
$$y(x) = 1 + W_0(C x), \qquad x \in \left(-\frac1{C e}, \infty\right)$$
and a solution
$$y(x) = 1 + W_{-1}(C x), \qquad x \in \left(-\frac1{C e}, 0\right)$$
If $C = 0$, we have the constant solution $y(x) = 1$.
If $C < 0$, there is a solution
$$y(x) = 1 + W_0(C x), \qquad x \in \left(-\infty, -\frac1{C e}\right)$$
and a solution
$$y(x) = 1 + W_{-1}(C x), \qquad x \in \left(0, -\frac1{C e}\right) .$$

Figure 1. Select solutions ($\color{#0000ff}{\textrm{blue solution}}$: $a = 0$, $C = 1$; $\color{#00bf00}{\textrm{green solution}}$: $a = -1$, $C = 1$); $\color{#ff00ff}{\textrm{magenta solution}}$ (constant): $a = 1, C = 0$)


I'll try to make this as rigorous as I can, especially with regards to removing the absolute values, as that can be a bit tricky to deal with. I will assume that we are only looking for solutions which are $C^1$ and defined on some interval.
So let's start with some observations:

The first is that the function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x,y)=\frac{y-1}{xy}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{xy}$$
on $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :x\neq0,y\neq0\}$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on all subsets $U$ of $\Omega$ bounded away from the coordinate axes, as
$$\lvert f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)\rvert=\left\lvert\int_{y_2}^{y_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{xy^2}\right\rvert\leq\sup_{(x_0,y_0)\in U}\frac{1}{\lvert x_0\rvert y_0^2}\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert$$
for all $(x,y_1),(x,y_2)\in U$. Thus, by Picard-Lindelöf, we have existence and uniqueness away from the coordinate axes.

The second observation is that $y(0)=1$ for any solution crossing the $y$-axis.

The third observation is that if $y(x_0)=1$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then either $x_0=0$, or $y(x)=1$ for all $x$ with the same sign as $x_0$ by the uniqueness of solutions.

The fourth observation is that no solution can cross the $x$-axis, as if $y(x)=0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$0=xy(x)y'(x)=y(x)-1=-1,$$
a contradiction.


With these observations at hand, we are now ready to tackle the problem.
As for what you've done, so far so good, so for a solution $y$ we have that
$$y(x)+\ln\lvert y(x)-1\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert+C.$$
for $x\neq0$ with $C\in\mathbb{R}$ some constant. Suppose that $y$ is not the constant function $y(x)\equiv1$. Let $I$ be some subinterval of either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. We work with the equation on $I$. Recall that, by the third observation, we either have that $y(x)>1$ for all $x\in I$ or that $y(x)<1$ for all $x\in I$. Suppose first that we have the first case. Then
$$\ln((y(x)-1)e^{y(x)-1})+1=y(x)+\ln\lvert y(x)-1\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert+C,$$
so
$$(y(x)-1)e^{y(x)-1}=D\lvert x\rvert$$
for all $x\in I$, for some constant $D>0$. As the right-hand side is positive for all $x\in I$, we can solve the equation using the Lambert $W$ function so that
$$y(x)-1=W_0(D\lvert x\rvert),$$
and consequently
$$y(x)=W_0(D\lvert x\rvert)+1.$$
for all $x\in I$. Observe that, by letting $I$ be maximal (as a subset of $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$), this gives us the (unique) solution on the whole of $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. This takes care of the case then $y(x)>1$ for all $x\in I$. Two cases remain: $0<y(x)<1$ for all $x\in I$, and $y(x)<0$ for all $x\in I$ (recall the fourth observation).
Suppose that $0<y(x)<1$ for all $x\in I$. Then, similar to before, we have that
$$(1-y(x))e^{y(x)-1}=D\lvert x\rvert,$$
with $D>0$, and so
$$(y(x)-1)e^{y(x)-1}=-D\lvert x\rvert.$$
Now if $D\lvert x\rvert>\frac{1}{e}$, i.e. if $\lvert x\rvert>\frac{1}{De}$, then this equation cannot be solved, and so $I\subseteq\left[-\frac{1}{De},\frac{1}{De}\right]$. Now this equation in general has two solutions, however the condition that $y(x)-1>-1$ for all $x\in I$ gives us the uniquely defined solution
$$y(x)-1=W_0(-D\lvert x\rvert),$$
i.e.
$$y(x)=W_0(-D\lvert x\rvert)+1$$
for all $x\in I$. Taking $I$ to be maximal, so that $I$ is either $\left(0,\frac{1}{De}\right)$ or $\left(-\frac{1}{De},0\right)$ this takes care of this case.
Finally, suppose that $y(x)<0$ for all $x\in I$. Then, just as in the previous case, we obtain the equation
$$(y(x)-1)e^{y(x)-1}=-D\lvert x\rvert.$$
In this case, however, the solution to this equation is
$$y(x)-1=W_{-1}(-D\lvert x\rvert),$$
i.e.
$$y(x)=W_{-1}(-D\lvert x\rvert)+1$$
for all $x\in I$. We also get the same maximal $I$ as in the previous case.
Now using that $W_0'(0)=1$, it is not hard to see that if we patch together these solutions on the positive and negative real lines, then they must have the same constant $D$ buth with different signs on both sides (assuming we have the solutions involving $W_0$). For the solutions involving $W_{-1}$, these solutions cannot cross the $y$-axis, as $W_{-1}(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\downarrow0$. Thus to summarize we have the following maximal solutions:

$y(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
$y(x)=W_0(Dx)+1$ for all $x\in\left(-\frac{1}{De},\infty\right)$, with $D>0$ arbitrary.
$y(x)=W_0(Dx)+1$ for all $x\in\left(-\infty,-\frac{1}{De}\right)$, with $D<0$ arbitrary.
$y(x)=W_{-1}(D x)+1$ for all $x\in\left(-\frac{1}{De},0\right)$, with $D>0$ arbitrary.
$y(x)=W_{-1}(Dx)+1$ for all $x\in\left(0,-\frac{1}{De}\right)$, with $D<0$ arbitrary.

Furthermore, which solution one obtains is uniquely determined by the initial conditions.
